# How To Make Gunfire Animations?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

How do I make gunfire animations with blender? I never animated anything in blender except to build models. Here is a picture of my model:

[image: A10 - Bomber. Going to animate the guns. Made in Blender 2.70a]

Is there anything I can try to make gunfire animations?

Comment: Closed? really I was about to post the settings for a simple line emitting particle system, please reopen. Much easier and less steps than most editing questions.

Comment: @ideasman42 I already prepared an answer could you please reopen?

Comment: Answer posted here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15825049#15825049